# Extension of essence in redux

Tags: javascript, redux

My state looks like this:

```
state = {
  entities: {
    users: {},
    articles: {},
  },
  pagination: {
    articlesByUser: {
      1: { // userId = 1
        isFetching: true,
        ids: [],
      },
      2: { // userId = 2
        isFetching: true,
        ids: [],
      },
    },
  },
}
```

it's work fine for pages with lists, but the article models differ for the `index` route and `get` the route.

Response on `index` route:

```
$ curl http://api//articles
[{
  "id": 0,
  "user_id": 0,
  "title": "...",
  "short_description": "...",
  ...
}
...
]
```

Response on `get` route:

```
$ curl http://api//articles/0
{
  "id": 0,
  "user_id": 0,
  "title": "...",
  "body": "...",
  "meta": {...},
  "view_count": 100,
  ...
}
```

Entities are different. `GetModel` request extend `IndexModel`. Therefore state of `pagination` reducer should looks like this:

```
pagination: {
  articlesByUser: {
    1: { // userId = 1
      isFetching: true,
      ids: [],
    },
    2: { // userId = 2
      isFetching: true,
      ids: [],
    },
    ...
  },
  articleByArticleId: {
    1: { // articleId = 1
      isFetching: true,
    },
    ...
  }
},
```

How to better structure `pagination` reducer in this case for handle loading state (`isFetching = true`) for one and many of articles?

Comment: Why is the reducer call `pagination`, and what's wrong with the state shape you suggested yourself?

Comment: What's wrong with the name `paginatinion`? I think that my structure is redundant, because two reducers are created to describe one entity.

Comment: The state should be `{ users: {...}, articles: {...}}` as suggested by @riwu's below. If one user has many articles, you link article to user by having an array of article IDs inside the user in `state.user[userId]`. Can you elaborate on the pagination? What exactly is paginated? When you fetch `api/articles/0` is this all articles belonging to user 0? If so, you need to specifiy what the pagination parameters look like before anyone can give a helpful answer. They usually consist of limit, offset, and total amount: how many per page, how far you have fetched them, and how many in total.

Comment: No, when a request is made for `api/articles/0`, then the whole article comes (together with the full text, description and other meto information). While at the request on `api/articles` I get only a part of the information about the article (short description, title and picture)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what your references to models mean; my assumption is that you're talking about the models on the backend, but that doesn't really affect us here so I'm going to ignore them.

### Using actions for fetching and formatting data in Redux

Let's start with this statement:

> It works fine for pages with lists, but the article models differ for the index route and get the route

This doesn't actually matter! It is okay that the data is different between the routes (even if it isn't ideal).

I don't know where you are handling your API requests currently, but I recommend putting them into Redux Actions. Using the middleware [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) we can have functions in our action creators. Part of an action's job is to prepare data for the reducer. This means that we can use functions in actions to format the data so it always the same when it hits the reducer. This means we don't need to write many similar reducers to handle the same entity type, keeping things DRY and making it much, much easier to maintain.

In this scenario I would have three actions:

`getAllArticles()`

`getArticlesById(id)`

`putArticles(articles)`

The two get article actions would be responsible for making the request, formatting the data. They then take this data and pass it to `putArticles` which actually dispatches the action the reducer is listening for.

Your methods would look something like this:

```
const getAllArticles = () => {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
      fetch(yourRoute).then((json) => {
        const formattedData = json // format/normalize your data here
        dispatch(putArticles(formattedData))
      }
   }
}

const getArticleById = (id) => {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
      fetch(yourRoute + id).then((json) => {
        const formattedData = json // format/normalize your data here
        dispatch(putArticles(formattedData))
      }
   }
}

const putArticles = (articles) => {
   return {
      type: 'PUT_ARTICLES',
      payload: {articles}
   }
}
```

### Normalizing data

The next step I would look at is normalizing your data. You've actually done a pretty good job of splitting entities out and keeping paginated info separate from the actual entities list.

I would break your store down by entity type.

```
state = {
   articles: {
      entities: { /* each article by ID */},
      result: [/* array of ID, primary used for looping */],
      pagination: { /* various pagination methods */ }
   },
  ...
}
```

Normalizing the data prevents you form having nested resource lists (articles > users > comments, as an example). You've pretty much done this, formalizing it with a library like[Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) will allow you to standardize the way you handle data.

I would move pagination into the individual entity (user, article). This keeps things neatly separated by their type and prevents having this massive list of unrelated data.

Going deeply into normalization as a whole is outside of the scope of a SO question, but take a look at these two links:

[Normalizing Redux State Shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)

[Updating Normalized Data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/updating-normalized-data)

Comment: Your answer is beautiful, thank you! But I'm still asking more about how to structure a `pagination` reducer

Comment: How to handle loading state (`isFetching = true`) for one of article?

Answer (score 2):

> I think that my structure is redundant, because two reducers are created to describe one entity.

You can just use 2 entities: `users` and `articles` to store all users and articles data, including `isFetching` status and partial data from `api/articles`:

```
state = {
  users: {
    1: { // userId === 1
      name: 'John', // user properties
      articles: [1, 2, 5], // article ids associated with user
    }
  },
  articles: {
    1: { // articleId === 1
      title: '...',
      isFetching: true,
    }
  }
}
```

Then when you successfully retrieved an article from `api/articles/:id`, you can dispatch a `SET_ARTICLE_DATA` action with the article `id` and `data`, and replace the partial article data in your articles reducer (assuming you keep the articles state in a separate reducer):

```
case SET_ARTICLE_DATA:
  return {
    ...state, // clone existing articles
    [action.id]: { // replace article with id === `action.id` with received data
      ...state[action.id], // not needed if `action.data` has everything u need
      ...action.data,
      isFetching: false, // can use object destructuring on `state[action.id]` to remove this key too
    } 
  }
```